# SQL Count of date values that dont match hour and day in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem unique to a business process. My user needs to know how many dates, counted, are before a specific end time that do not match on the hour or the day.

Here is an example.

`AAA, 2016-03-15 16:00:28.967, 2016-03-15 16:02:58.487, 2016-03-17 14:01:24.243`

In the example above id `AAA` has 3 entries. I need to count only the ones that don't have a matching hour and day. So the actual count should come out to be 2.

I have to do this all in SQL and can't use a CTE. It needs to be either a sub select or some type of join.

Something like this.

```
SELECT id, date, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM x 
    WHERE day!=day 
    AND hour!=hour AND date < z
) AS DateCount
```

Results would be `AAA, 2`

I am thinking some type of recursive comparison but I am not sure how to accomplish this without a CTE.

Comment: I can't use a CTE because this is a count that is part of a larger statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a AS current_a, COUNT(*) AS b,day AS day, hour as hour, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM t 
     WHERE day != day 
     AND hour != hour 
     AND date < z ) as datecount
FROM t GROUP BY a ORDER by b DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can try something like this:

```
SELECT id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), [date], 120) AS [Date], COUNT(*) AS DateCount
FROM YourTable
WHERE [date] < #ENDDATE
GROUP BY id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), [date], 120)
```